# PermissionSet - Request Failed error

Tags: c#, .net, soap, communication, remoting

I have few projects communicating using ChannelSink, ServerSink and ClientSink.

I've upgraded the projects from .NET 2.0 to .NET 4.0. Before the upgrade everything worked fine.

Now, when I try to communicate , - for a specific message - my OnReceiveMessage isn't called and throwing the following exception:

> System.Security.SecurityException: Request failed
>
> Server stack trace:
>       at System.Array.InternalCreate(Void* elementType, Int32 rank, Int32* pLengths, Int32*
>
> pLowerBounds)
>       at System.Array.CreateInstance(Type elementType, Int32 Length)
>       at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.ObjectReader.ParseArray(ParseRecord
>   pr)
>       at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.ObjectReader.ParseObject(ParseRecord
>   pr)
>       at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.ObjectReader.Parse(ParseRecord
>   pr)
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.SoapHandler.StartChildren()
>       at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.SoapParser.ParseXML()
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.ObjectReader.Run()
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler,
>   ISerParser
>
> serParser)
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.SoapFormatter.Deserialize(Stream
>   serializationStream,
>
> HeaderHandler handler)
>       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CoreChannel.DeserializeSoapRequestMessage(Stream
>
> inputStream, Header[] h, Boolean bStrictBinding)
>       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Chanels.SoapServerFormatterSink.ProcessMessage
>
> (IServerChannelSinkStack sinkStack, IMessage requestMsg,
>   ITransportHeaders requestHeaders, Stream
>
> requestStream, IMessage& responseMsg, ITransportHeaders&
>   responseHeaders, Stream& responseStream)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:
>       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage (IMessage reqMsg, IMessage
>
> retMSg)
>       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)
>       .
>       . (some of my files)
>       . The action that failed was: Demand The type of the first permission that failed was: System.Security.PermissionSet The demand
>   was for:
>
> The only permitted permissions were:
>
> The method that caused that failure was:
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.ServerProcessing
>   ProcessMessage(System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.IServerChannelSinkStack,
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage,
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.ITransportHeaders, System.IO.Stream,
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.IMessage ByRef,
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.ITransportHeaders ByRef,
>   System.IO.Stream ByRef)

The thing is, if I create a dummy method and add it to the sinkstack - it calls it. even if I use the same proxy which denies the message.

Other thing is, The other messages are working just fine. only one type of messages isnt working from all the types iv'e created.

I haven't requested PermissionSet at my app at all, Any help?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I'm getting the same problem since upgrading to .net 4.0, and only where the method signature involves arrays. Oddly it's broken on my local dev environment but exactly the same code works on our test server. Still investigating here...

Answer (score 2):

Pah - should have guess that 5 minutes after posting on stack exchange I would find it. I simply had to replace:

```
<formatter ref="soap" />
```

by

```
<formatter ref="soap" typeFilterLevel="Full" />
```

The MSDN documentation for typeFilterLevel explains what's happening, although I'm not entirely sure why an array isn't considered a "basic" type